# BcdDivide function behave differently in Delphi XE and XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

`FmtBcd.pas` has been extensively revised rewritten in Delphi XE2. In one of my projects, I have a case that uses a division operation on two `Bcd` values, but the two versions yield different results. In the worst case, the Delphi XE2 may throw a `Bcd overflow error`.

Example: Running the following code in Delphi XE2 console apps:

```
var A, B, C, D: TBcd;
begin
  A := StrToBcd('1');
  B := StrToBcd('3');
  BcdDivide(A, B, C);
  WriteLn(BcdToStr(C));

  try
    BcdMultiply(C, C, D);
    WriteLn(BcdToStr(D));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.Message);
  end;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Output of the above will be:

```
0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
BCD overflow
```

The variable `C` contains a Bcd Value with 63 decimal places of specificity. Performing a second `BcdMultiply` operation on variable `C` will cause a `Bcd overflow error`.

However, to run the same code in Delphi XE yields the following result without any exception prompt:

```
0.3333333333
0.11111111108888888889
```

Could anyone please suggest a best-practice method for resolving this problem?

Comment: Hard to say anything else except that this is a bug in XE2.

Comment: I have reported to http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=103106

Comment: Same results when compiled for Win32 or Win64?

Comment: @François: Both Win32 and Win64 in XE2 produce same result.

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=103106 Status is still Open on Oct 19. 7 Month still checking....

Comment: Sorry to ask but what's your question here? You're just making a statement. If the supplied lib is buggy then you can simply reimplement the used functions. Or use the ones from the working version. Whatever.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Yes, it's been fixed for ages now.

Answer (score 6):

The code in the question produces the expected output in XE2 update 4. Note that update 3 produces the bad output and so clearly the fix arrived with update 4. Also, XE3 produces the expected output.